# Google OAuth does not return refresh_token in authlib.starlette_client

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, authlib, starlette

Hi I am developing a web app with authlib/FastAPI/Google for the login process and want to keep `refresh_token` so that I can keep the user in the app for enough time.

I followed the standard procedure as in https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/starlette.html

```py
oauth = OAuth()
oauth.register(
  name='google',
  client_id='xxx',
  client_secret='yyy',
  api_base_url='https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/',
  access_token_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  authorize_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
  jwks_uri='https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs',
  client_kwargs={
    'scope': 'email openid',
    'access_type': 'offline',
    'prompt': 'consent',
  }
)

from starlette.requests import Request

@app.get("/login")
def login_via_google(request: Request):
    redirect_uri = 'https://example.com/auth'
    return await oauth.google.authorize_redirect(request, redirect_uri)

@app.get("/auth")
def auth_via_google(request: Request):
    token = await oauth.google.authorize_access_token(request)
    user = await oauth.google.parse_id_token(request, token)
    return dict(user)
```

However, the token does not contain `refresh_token` even though I specified `access_type='offline'`. In case my app is already registered in my account, I added a param of `prompt='content'` too.

Am I missing something?

Additionally, is keeping a `refresh_token` the best way for a long-running user app? I don't like to bother a user to login multiple times.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue myself, digging through the code in the debugger it turns out that any extra keyword params to the `authorize_redirect` function eventually end up as parameters on the url if nothing consumes them before that point.

So an easy solution to the problem is to just modify that call to

```py
return await oauth.google.authorize_redirect(request, redirect_uri, access_type="offline")
```

Comment: I confirm that this works. Thanks, dear sir.

Answer (score 1):

Most scripting languages only return the refresh_token on the first time the user is authenticated. It is assumed assume that you have saved it in your system and are using it so wont need another one.  So all other attempts to authenticate the user will not include it.

you can try to force them to [re-consent](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#re-consent) however i am not sure if this will force a new refresh token.  Which it appears you are doing so it doesn't work.

In which case you probably need to revoke the users access and request it again. Unless you have the token then [Token revoke](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke) then have them login again and you should see a refresh token

If all else fails have the user go into their google account and remove your applications access to their account and then try and login.  That will be like starting over completely and will defiantly give you a refresh token.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! But I actually did all of them already as you can see `'prompt': 'consent'` is already in the code snippet. And I removed the app from my account management, but it's still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too. It seems like only some parameters are allowed in the `client_kwargs`:

```
EXTRA_AUTHORIZE_PARAMS = (
    'response_mode', 'nonce', 'prompt', 'login_hint'
)
```

Perhaps the author was trying to disallow parameters that were implementation specific? One workaround seems to be adding the `access_type=offline` to the `authorize_url`:

```
authorize_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline'
```